# Periodic function example

Tags: functions

I do not understand the final determination of $n=3$ in the below.  while I understand the substitutions of $x=0$ and $x=1$, why in the final section does adding (i) and (ii) give
$$f(3) + f(4) = f(3) - f(1)?$$

should it not equal
$$f(3) + f(4) = f(5) - f(1)$$

see below:

---

A function $f (x)$ is periodic if there exists a number $n$ so that $f(x + n) = f (x)$ for all $x$. Here, n is the period of the function.

Let us take an example:

If $f (x + 3) = f (x + 2) - f (x + 1)$, what is the value of $n$ if $f (1) = -f (1 + n)$?

We have: $f (x + 3) = f (x + 2) - f (x + 1)$

Substituting different values of $x$:

$$x = 0 : f (3) = f (2) - f (1) \dots (i)\\
x = 1 : f (4) = f (3) - f (2)\dots (ii)$$

Adding (i) and (ii):

$$\begin{align}f (3) + f (4) &= f (3) - f (1)\\
f (1) &= -f(4)\\
f (1) &= -f(1 + 3)\\
n &= 3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding the two equations gives

$$f(3)+f(4) = (f(2)-f(1)) + (f(3)-f(2))$$

which simplifies to

$$f(3)+f(4)=-f(1)+f(3)$$

and further to $$f(4)=-f(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

We're adding the left-hand sides together, and the right-hand sides together. The two left-hand sides are $f(3)$ and $f(4)$. Adding them together gives $f(3) + f(4)$.

The two right-hand sides are $f(2) - f(1)$ and $f(3) - f(2)$. Adding them together yields
$$
f(3) - f(2) + f(2) - f(1) = f(3) - f(1)
$$
Equating the two sums (which is legal, because they are sums of things that were equal), we get
$$
f(3) + f(4) = f(3) - f(1)\\
f(4) = -f(1)\\
-f(4) = f(1)
$$